# Case expression during update one table to another

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables, one is called `BI` and the other is called `DP`.

I want to update my `DP` table columns (`Brand` and `BrandDescription`) with the values from `BI` table columns (`BrandName` And `Description`) respectively.

The Key column from `BI` table is `ChainID` which is numeric 1 and 3, where as in `DP` it is `Chaincode` which is string.

- `Chainid` 1 has to mapped with both `Chaincode` FSC and PRC
- `Chainid` 3 has to mapped with only `Chaincode` EPRC

Here's my data:

```
CREATE TABLE BI 
(
    CHAINID INT,
    BrandName VARCHAR (100),
    Description VARCHAR (100)
)

INSERT INTO BI
    SELECT 1, 'Sony', 'Bravia' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 'Panasonic','TH-55MX'

CREATE TABLE DP 
(
    CHAINCODE VARCHAR (50),
    Brand VARCHAR (100),
    BrandDescription VARCHAR (100)
)

INSERT INTO DP
    SELECT 'FSC', 'SNY','BraV' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'PRC', 'SNY','BRAV' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'EPRC', 'PAN','INDI'
```

Expected output (`DP` table) after update:

| ChainCode | Brand | BrandDescription |
| --- | --- | --- |
| FSC | SONY | Bravia |
| PRC | SONY | Bravia |
| EPRC | Panasonic | TH-55MX |

Highly appreciate your suggestions.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do it would be to add a mapping table between `CHAINID` and  `CHAINCODE`, and then use a simple `UPDATE` statement with a 3-way join:

```
DECLARE @Map AS TABLE
(
  Id int, 
  Code varchar(50)  
);

INSERT INTO @Map (Id, Code) VALUES 
(1, 'FSC'),
(1, 'PRC'),
(3, 'EPRC');

UPDATE DP
SET Brand = BI.BrandName,
    BrandDescription = BI.Description
FROM DP 
JOIN @Map As M
  ON DP.CHAINCODE = M.Code
JOIN BI
  ON M.Id = BI.CHAINID
```

You can see a live demo on [<kbd>db<>fiddle</kbd>](https://dbfiddle.uk/mPT2fJWT)